# Variable Within Single and Double Quotes

Tags: php, syntax-error

How would I get this to work?

```
$step = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?&step=';
echo "<form action=". $step ."2"><select>";
```

It's giving me a (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<') on the second line. Halp?

Comment: Bonus points? How would I get the actual url.php?step= to correspond with a specifically defined content? Code looks like this:
 `code` if (empty($_GET['step'])) { } elseif ($_GET['step'] = 2) { }

Comment: Take note of your syntax highlighting. You should notice a color difference near the end of the string. This should be your first hint. Also, beware of the security (XSS) concerns with `PHP_SELF`: http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/php-server-vars-not-safe-in-forms-or-links/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape your quotes inside of strings:

```
echo "<form action=\"${step}2\"><select>";
```

That will fix your problem, but it would probably be a good idea to escape the attribute value before putting it in the HTML as well:

```
echo "<form action=\"" . htmlspecialchars($step) . "2\"><select>";
```

Answer (score 3):

The " after the 2 ends the string.  Escape it or use single quotes.

```
$step = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?&step=';
echo "<form action=\"", $step , "2\"><select>";
```

Comment: If you escape it (instead of removing it), the HTML is missing the quote at the beginning of the arguments value.

Comment: @hakre :) Good catch.  I was too focused on the syntax error, not the resulting html.

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the double-quotes, or using a combination of double/singe:

```
echo "<form action=\"". $step ."2\"><select>";
```

or

```
echo '<form action="'. $step .'2"><select>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try actually paying attention to colour coding. Or use an editor that has colour-coding if yours doesn't.

```
echo '<form action="'.$step.'2"><select>';
```

Comment: I do I'm just unfamiliar with color meanings and proofreading myself since I'm new at php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$step = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?&step=';
echo "<form action=". $step .'"2"><select>';
```

or

```
$step = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?&step=';
echo "<form action=". $step ."\"2\""><select>";
```